# SSO Application Endpoint URL not working

Tags: single-sign-on, endpoint, pingfederate

We am trying to setup PingFederate version 7.2.1 on AWS.

In our setup, PingFederate is acting as a Service Provider (SP) and our client ADFS is acting as an Identity Provider (IdP).

After setting up an IdP Connection at our end, the following SSO Application Endpoint URL was generated:

https://aa.bb.ccc.dd/sp/startSSO.ping?PartnerIdpId=http://adfs.clientname.com/adfs/services/trust

When I run the part of the link "https://aa.bb.ccc.dd/sp/startSSO.ping" in the URL, nothing happens. This link should go to the client's ADFS site where we should get an error message saying that login not allowed.

We have a Production Environment (hosted in the cloud on IBM Softlayer) where this is working as expected.

Can anyone please suggest why the SSO Endpoint URL might not be working.

I am using the same FederationMetadata.xml which we had used in Production.

Thank You

Sugam Khetrapal

Comment: What do you mean, "it doesn't work." What happens? Does the request make it to PF? Is there a PF error generated? What do the logs show?

Comment: Hi Ian, the link https://aa.bb.cc.dd/sp/startSSO.ping goes to the ADFS host now. But when we type the link https://aa.bb.cc.dd/sp/startSSO.ping?PartnerIdpId=http://adfs.clientname.com/adfs/services/trust first we see an error message stating the reference no (which changes upon pressing F5 everytime) but after that it seems that the request is not receiving any response from the ADFS host. We were hoping to get a login page from the ADFS host. I will share the logs output as well. Thanks

Comment: The Reference value/code points to a specific event in the ../pingfederate/log/server.log. Search the server.log for a more detailed description. Chances are your PartnerIdpId value doesn't match what is in your IDP Connection "Entity ID" field.